# Why different gotra marriage is not practiced in North India fully?

Tags: marriage

> "asapiNDA cha yA mAtuH asagotrA cha yApituH 
>   sA dvijAnAM prashastA strI dArakarmaNyamaithunI"

**- Manu Smriti**

> "asamAnArSheyAmaspRShTamaithunAM avaravayasIM bhAryAM vindeta"

**-vasiShTha**

> "mAtRtaH panchamAdUrdhvaM pitRtaH saptamAditi"

**-yAJjavalkya**

As per the above, a boy should not marry a girl who is sapiNDa that is descendants of the same womb or a girl who is of the same gotra as the his father. However there's no bar on a 7th gen boy marrying a 5th gen girl of the same lineage. A boy marrying his paternal aunt's daughter or a maternal uncle's daughter therefore doesn't contravene these provisions and hence permitted. However, we do see girls marrying own maternal uncles in south I don't know how.

other provisions in regard to marriage is that the girl should not be elder to the boy and should not have had pre-marital relationship.

**My doubt is why is same thing not practiced in North India?**

- So for a background, In North paternal aunt's daughter and maternal
  uncle's daughter are treated as sisters even though their gotra are
  different considering their father's gotra.

Comment: @Triyugi Hmm looks like a dupe then, however it has no answer as per ask.

Comment: What are the translations of those verses from smritis you have quoted? Can you find them and write because many can't understand?

Comment: I wrote the translation below. @Sarva

Comment: Do all the three say the same? Isn't it a summary and not a translation?