# If sagotra mariages are prohibited, why did Krishna marry Satyabhama?

Tags: scripture, krishna, marriage, yadavas, satyabhama

Krishna and Satyabhama ( Sathyabhama ) shared a common paternal ancestor, Anamitra.

Answer (score 2):

The rule according to rig Veda is that one cannot share a common paternal ancestor for 7 generations and maternal ancestor for 5 generations.

I had encountered this in a book on Rig Veda, but I am not able to recollect it.
Also [**Manusmriti 3.5**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199777.html) says:

> "Marriage should he performed with persons not belonging to the same Pravara;—above the Seventh grade among his paternal relations;—also beyond persons of the same seed;—and above the fifth grade among maternal relations."

Animitra was at least 11 generations ago for Krishna (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrishni)

Gotras I believe are an easy way to enforce this rule.

Comment: Why the down vote? It will be helpful if can you please explain your reasons? It will help expand the answer

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, but could be because you have cited Wikipedia as source which is not a valid source on this site. :)

Comment: Ah well, let me edit the answer. I had read the statement in a book, now I am unable to find it

Comment: You may want to look into smriti especially manu smriti. it covers gotra and marriage.

Comment: Also check this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35382/647

Comment: I guess that answer pretty much provides the source

Comment: Let's continue discussion in chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism

Comment: joined the chat

Comment: You may want to change your above quote of paternal 5 generations and maternal 7 generations to the opposite. 7 On the paternal and 5 on the maternal. That’s what all scriptures say, including the Manusmriti you’ve quoted. Also the one you’ve quoted is Gautama Dharmasutra and not Manusmriti

Comment: @archit do you have other sources, can you please comment?

Comment: All your sources are mentioned below the Manusmriti verse cited. The Guatama Dharmasutra is also mentioned there only (that’s how I know) :D also it would be nice if you could give sources for Anamitra being more than 7 generations above Krishna and Satyabhama

Answer (score 0):

In case of kshatriyas, gotra-pravara is inherited from their purohita and not from a common ancestor hence krShNa-satyabAmA marriage is possible assuming both families had purohitas belonging to different gotra (in addition to 7/5 generation rule of shatapAtha brAhmaNa 1:8:3:6) :

[aitareya brAhmaNa book 7 ch.4](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104262/page/n182/mode/1up) :

> *Thence (if the sacrificer be a Ksattriya) they (the Brahma speakers) ask as to how the inauguration (diksa), which is, in the case of a
> Brahman being initiated, announced by the formula, ' the Brahmana is
> initiated,” should be promulgated in the case of the sacrificer being
> a Ksattriya ? The answer is, The formula, “ the Brahmana is
> initiated,” is to be kept when a Ksattriya is being initiated ; **the
> ancestral fire of the Ksattriya’s house-priest is to be mentioned**.
> This, this is certainly so.*
>
> *[479] Having laid aside his own implements (weapons), and taking up those of the Brahma, and having thus become Brahma, by means of the
> Brahma form, he returned to the sacrifice. Therefore they should
> proclaim him as a Diksita, **with the name of his house-priest’s
> ancestral fires, and invoke them also in the Pravara prayer**.*

[aitareya brAhmaNa book 7 ch.5](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104262/page/n187/mode/1up) :

> *The Ksattriya (when drinking the juice of the Nyagrodha) enters the form of the Brahma by the medium of another (not direct), viz, through
> the relationship of his purohita (with the Brahmans), his own Diksa
> (at which the king himself was made a Brahmana for a little while),
> and **the Pravara of his Purohita**.*

Answer (score -1):

Satyabhama and Sri krishna both are Yadavas but their gotra is different just like how Arjuna Subhadra are chandravanshi but gotras are different.