# Pravara of Suryavamsa Kshatriyas

Tags: caste-system, kshatriya, gotra, suryavansh, vaishya

From the question given here: [Who is the Vaishya Rishi Sankila?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16098/who-is-the-vaishya-rishi-sankila),
It is evident that true vedic kshatriyas must have a three-rishi (pravara) "Manava, Aida, Paururavasa" for the Hotri, followed by their gOtra. Vaisyas must have the following:  three-rishi (pravara) "Bhalandana, Vatsapra, Mankila" for the Hotri, followed by the gOtra of their priest. This is according to the Boudhayana Dharma Sutras as documented in above question.

My questions are:

**1) How does this pravara cover the suryavamsha?** Pururavas is the progenitor of the chandravamsha (discussed here: [How are the lunar race and solar race originated?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/how-are-the-lunar-race-and-solar-race-originated) )

**2) Should those claiming to be vaisyas and kshatriyas be reciting those respective pravarAs when doing abhivAdaye** (if at all any such kshatriyAs and vaisyAs exist)?

**3) So Kshatriyas and Vaisyas need not worry about sagOtra marriages as long as the prescribed 7 paternal generations have passed?** (ref to the 7 generation rule: [If sagotra mariages are prohibited, why did Krishna marry Satyabhama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43579/if-sagotra-mariages-are-prohibited-why-did-krishna-marry-satyabhama)) Per question discussed above, it seems their gotras can change according to the current purOhit of their family.

Comment: multiple questions. see forum rules

Comment: gotra/pravara of true kshatriya is that of their family purohit.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda sorry! I will keep this is mind next time.

Comment: @brahmāstra this is what I thought too. But their pravarAs can change according to the priest (example would be the Janakas from the Ikshvaku line). Another example are the ChAlukyAs, who had different gOtrAs after a couple generations. The dharma sUtrAs on the other hand say that seminally, the Kshatriyas would have the aforementioned pravarA but can use their family purOhit’s pravarA. Did you get a chance to read the sources I shared?

Comment: The dharma sUtrAs clearly state that Kshatriyas and Vaisyas need not bar sagotra marriages if they know they are not related past 7 generations because they have no true seminal rishi pravarAs. I request you to read the sources I’ve attached to answer my question. Thank you

Comment: Also “manava” is a gOtra found in Rajputs and other “KshatriyAs” today.

Comment: There is nothing like Kṣatriyas can have only three-ṛṣi pravara. The pravara and gotra & pravara of the ruling Kṣatriyas usually depended on the gotra & pravara of their kulaguru/kulapurohita. And there are different kulapurohitas of different vaṁśas. Even the single vaṁśa of Candra was split into many branches and they had their different purohitas. These purohitas served the same line for generations. And not all Sūryavaṁśīs would have the same pravara. The pravara recitation becomes important in yajñas, etc. And those can be only done by dvijas.

Comment: The 7 generation gap rule is for the case of sapiṇḍas, not sagotras. One who says that rule applies to sagotras, is simply speaking against dharmaśāstras and doesn't understand basic vivāha criteria as laid down in gṛhyasūtras, etc. It doesn't matter if you are Brāhmaṇa, Kṣatriya, Vaiśya or Śūdra, two people of the same gotra cannot have vivāha. If they do have vivāha, that would be null, and a pāpakarman. Furthermore, the child born of that union would be a cāṇḍāla.